# CORS still enforced after disabling Chrome web security?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, xss

I'm trying to grab data from one website and use it to write something into another website (using JQuery/Javascript). Understandably, the same origin rules weren't going to let that happen, but I figured disabling web security/CORS on my browser should fix that problem. For some reason, I can't get the policy disabled in Chrome, and I can't figure out why.

I've tried launching Chrome with --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\chromeTemp"`

I expected to be able to open a new tab, access 'document' in the console, and find a link I want to 'click', but instead I got

`VM186:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin <url> from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

I thought this would no longer be blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there might be an open bug for this, possibly try an older chrome version.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=840124

See Last Comment on workaround:

"The workaround is to download an old version of Chrome as a portable app : https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Google%20Chrome%20Portable/ (version 66.0.3359.181 still works). It's the one I use when I'm developing..."